# PHP mysql из БД

Tags: mysql

Как сделать чтобы поиск происходил по двум столбцам?

```
<?php
include '../connection.php';
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
mysql_select_db("questions");
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM films";
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
?>
Введите ключевое слово или текст.
<form action="" method="GET" name="form">
<input name="q" type="text"> <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
<?php

$search_slovo = $_GET['q'];
if(isset($search_slovo)){
if(empty($search_slovo)) {exit ("Вы не ввели данные");}}

echo " Вы искали: $search_slovo";

if ((isset($search_slovo))) {
$search_name= mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `name` FROM `films` WHERE `name` LIKE '%$search_slovo%' ");
if (mysqli_num_rows($conn, $search_name) != 0) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_name)) {
echo "Результаты поиска:" . $row['name'];
}
} else {
echo " Ничего не найдено";
}
} else {
echo "Введен пустой запрос";
}
?>
```

Но так не получается

```
<?php
include '../connection.php';
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
mysql_select_db("questions");
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM films";
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
?>
Введите ключевое слово или текст.
<form action="" method="GET" name="form">
<input name="q" type="text"> <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
<?php

$search_slovo = $_GET['q'];
if(isset($search_slovo)){
if(empty($search_slovo)) {exit ("Вы не ввели данные");}}

echo " Вы искали: $search_slovo";

if ((isset($search_slovo))) {
$search_name= mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `name`,`year` FROM `films` WHERE `name`,`year` LIKE '%$search_slovo%' ");
if (mysqli_num_rows($conn, $search_name) != 0) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_name)) {
echo "Результаты поиска:" . $row['name'];
}
} else {
echo " Ничего не найдено";
}
} else {
echo "Введен пустой запрос";
}
?>
```

Comment: Надо `WHERE 'name' LIKE '%$search_slovo% OR 'year' LIKE '%$search_slovo%`

Comment: SELECT * FROM `films` WHERE 'name' LIKE '%$search_slovo%' OR 'year' LIKE '%$search_slovo%' не работает (

Comment: Ошибку то говорит какую-нибудь?

Comment: нет не показывает!

Comment: Подробности пожалуйста. Возвращается `Ничего не найдено`? Тогда покажите данные в таблице и какой в итоге у вас получается запрос.

Comment: Ага... введёт юзер чёнить типа "Экипаж 2016"... и что дадут эти самые,  которые с OR? **@haykhaen** хотите в одном поле задавать критерии для поиска о нескольким полям - идите на поклон к полнотекстовому поиску, это его вотчина.